# Importing mutable variables from one python code to another

Tags: python-2.7, pbs, qsub

I have two Python codes. Code `Python_A` consists of a function and returns values `val1`, `val2`, `val3`. Code `Python_B` consists of a function whose argument values have to be `arg1 = val1`, `arg2 = val2`, `arg3 = val3`. How do I implement this?

The sequence of steps in which I would want this to happen is:

1. Code `Python_A` is executed
2. Submit a PBS job to a multiprocessor cluster
   which invokes a function from code `Python_B` that has to have its arguments as `val1`, `val2`, `val3`.

Several posts have shown ways of importing stationary values from one python code into another. But, none could be found which show importing mutable values.

How to get this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of a variable won't generally be saved once a script has completed running. To save a variable, one can write it out to a file, either directly, if it's some thing simple like a string or float, or using a serialized like pickle (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or JSON if it's a more complex data structure. Then reload the values when you want to use them in a new script.